# Typeahead will not display fields

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-typeahead

I am trying to get Twitter's Typeahead box to work on a text field so I can ultimately use it for a autocomplete function in unison with a database with google maps api. I can't even get the box to drop down with a a bunch of sample values and I do not know what I am doing wrong.

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#autocomplete .typeahead').typeahead({
  name: 'accounts',
  local: ['Audi', 'BMW', 'Bugatti', 'Ferrari', 'Ford', 'Lamborghini', 'Mercedes Benz', 'Porsche', 'Rolls-Royce', 'Volkswagen']
});
});
```

html:

```
<div class="col-sm-12" id = "filters" style="height:75px;">
    <div class="col-sm-3" id = "search"> 
        <form class="navbar-form">
            <div class="form-group" style="display:inline;">
                <div class="input-group">
                    <input type="text" placeholder="City/State/Zip" class="typeahead" id = "autocomplete">
                    <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span></span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>                         
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Have you tried _$('#autocomplete, .typeahead')_?

Answer (score 0):

Try re-arranging your id back onto the div field, doing this with your html:

```
<div class="col-sm-12" id = "filters" style="height:75px;">
    <div class="col-sm-3" id = "search"> 
        <form class="navbar-form">
            <div class="form-group" style="display:inline;">
                <div class="input-group" id="autocomplete">
                    <input type="text" placeholder="City/State/Zip" class="typeahead">
                    <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span></span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>                         
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Which engine of the typeahead.js are you using? The basic one or the Bloodhound? They have example codes at https://twitter.github.io/typeahead.js/examples/ you should just try out those samples first